# AutoHotkey (AHK): GetKeyState not recognizing keypress made by ControlSend

Tags: state, autohotkey

I have a very complex script that depresses a key, and needs to check at cerrtain points whether that key is still depressed or not, so GetKeyState seemed perfect, but I could not get it to work, so I made a simple script doing only that, and it still doesn't recognize the state.

The script is as follows:

```
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
    SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
    ~#Right::
    ControlSend,, {d down}, ahk_pid 6920
    Loop{
        GetKeyState, dState, d
        ;MsgBox, d Key State: %dState%
        SplashTextOn,300,50, AutoNavigatorInfo, d Key State: %dState%
        WinMove, AutoNavigatorInfo, , 300, 0  ; Move the splash window to the top left corner.
    }
```

Sadly, the splashText window I use keeps relaying dState as `U`.  Very odd seeing as in the test window I am using, it is interacting properly with the d key depressed.

Comment: Your script displays in splash text `U` when `d key` is not pressed and `D` when `d key` is pressed. `GetKeyState` works as it should. What and when you exactly need to splash text to display? What you think `GetKeyState` is doing wrong?

Comment: No vasili it is not detecting it.  As you can see in the script, ControlSend IS setting the d key down and leaving it down, that works, but GetKeytate never shows te d key as pressed, it ALWAYS shows it as U, it SHOULD show the dState as D, not U.  I cannot get it to detect the KeyState at all.  

If I use Send instead of ControlSend, then it works, but I need ControlSend for certain window functions, such as sending commandby PID.

Either way, I want to detect keystate in conjunction with ControlSend, is there another way to detect a keystate set in this way?

Comment: I only used the SplashText to debug and tell me what the dState variable contained.  This is just a test script.  Run it and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with **blackholyman** "GetKeyState will not work for controlsend as GetKeyState Gets the global system state of the key but controlsend only sets the state locally i.e the key state is only set for one control or window."

But if you need "ControlSend for certain window functions, such as sending commandby PID" I think you can do it with [Send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) command too. Use [WinActivate](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) to activate window that you need to send key and after use [Send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) to send key. You can use PID with [WinActivate](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) command instead of [Wintitle](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) parameter, more about it here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm

Try this code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
~#Right::
WinActivate, ahk_pid 6920
Send, {d down}
Loop{
    GetKeyState, dState, d
    ;MsgBox, d Key State: %dState%
    SplashTextOn,300,50, AutoNavigatorInfo, d Key State: %dState%
    WinMove, AutoNavigatorInfo, , 300, 0  ; Move the splash window to the top left corner.
}
```

Comment: I do agree this can be done, but the flipping of windows was what i was trying to avoind as I want to be working on other windows while this runs in the background.  Sadly, it doesn't seem doable with AhK :(

Answer (score 2):

GetKeyState will not work for controlsend as GetKeyState Gets the global system state of the key but controlsend only sets the state locally i.e the key state is only set for one control or window.

Comment: That makes sense, i was worried that might be the case :(